# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 very small command line

Tags: command-line, build, visual-studio-2012, font-size

Today I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and I came across a problem that the command line when I start the project has a very small font and can't be read. You do not know how to set it to normal? Thank you for your advice.

Operating system: Windows 8 64bit Czech

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the Command Window? Please clarify.

Comment: What does your command prompt look like on its own?
[Start] + [R] -> "cmd" -> [Enter]

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. I'm talking about Command Window...

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you're talking about the window for a console application. The Command Window is an IDE window in VS.

Comment: RE: Dandy: It's also very small. So the error is somewhere else than in Visual Studio...

Comment: Here is the solution: Turn on cmd.exe and right click on the mouse to change the size. It's really simple, but it happened to me the first time and I was looking for a bug elsewhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click on the top of the window and choose 'Defaults',  edit the size settings, save and load the command window again

Comment: Yes, it's true. I also came to it. Thank you very much!